# Round date to next weekday in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate, bizdays

I'm currently struggling with some date transformations in R. I have a large dataset of financial data with a date column. Since securities are not traded on the weekend, I need to have only weekdays in my dataset. How can I round the dates in this column to the previous weekday? So each Saturday and Sunday should be transformed to the previous Friday. in the extract below, the the first date is a Saturday and the second a Sunday. Now I would like to transform these into 2007-03-02 and leave the other rows as they are.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
Ticker Date       mean_PX_ASK mean_PX_BID Agency 
<chr>    <date>           <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
1 ABNANV 2007-03-03       102.        102.  Moody's
2 ABNANV 2007-03-04       102.        102.  Moody's
3 ABNANV 2007-03-12       102.        102.  Moody's
4 ABNANV 2007-03-12       102.        102.  Moody's
5 ABNANV 2008-09-17        88.9        88.4 Fitch  
6 ABNANV 2008-09-17        88.9        88.4 Fitch
```

Glad for any kind of help!

Comment: You have tagged your question [bizdays] but did apparently not bother to check its manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution could be using `case_when` from `dplyr` to check if `weekday` for that day is "Saturday" or "Sunday" and subtract the days accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Day = weekdays(Date), 
         Date = case_when(Day == "Saturday" ~ Date - 1, 
                          Day == "Sunday" ~ Date - 2, 
                          TRUE ~ Date)) %>%
   select(-Day)


#  Ticker       Date mean_PX_ASK mean_PX_BID  Agency
#1 ABNANV 2007-03-02       102.0       102.0 Moody's
#2 ABNANV 2007-03-02       102.0       102.0 Moody's
#3 ABNANV 2007-03-12       102.0       102.0 Moody's
#4 ABNANV 2007-03-12       102.0       102.0 Moody's
#5 ABNANV 2008-09-17        88.9        88.4   Fitch
#6 ABNANV 2008-09-17        88.9        88.4   Fitch
```

---

With `bizdays` we need to create a calendar using `create.calendar` and default `weekdays`. We can then use `adjust.previous` to get the previous working day.

```
library(bizdays)
cal <- create.calendar("Actual", weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"))
adjust.previous(df$Date, cal)

#[1] "2007-03-02" "2007-03-02" "2007-03-12" "2007-03-12" "2008-09-17" "2008-09-17"
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in a single line without any packages or `ifelse` if we use a named vector

```
df$Date <- with(df,  Date - setNames(rep(0:2, c(5, 1, 1)), 1:7)[format(Date, "%u")])
df
#  Ticker       Date mean_PX_ASK mean_PX_BID  Agency
#1 ABNANV 2007-03-02       102.0       102.0 Moody's
#2 ABNANV 2007-03-02       102.0       102.0 Moody's
#3 ABNANV 2007-03-12       102.0       102.0 Moody's
#4 ABNANV 2007-03-12       102.0       102.0 Moody's
#5 ABNANV 2008-09-17        88.9        88.4   Fitch
#6 ABNANV 2008-09-17        88.9        88.4   Fitch
```

#### Benchmarks

Using a bigger dataset

```
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e7), ]

system.time({
df1 %>%
  mutate(Day = weekdays(Date), 
         Date = case_when(Day == "Saturday" ~ Date - 1, 
                          Day == "Sunday" ~ Date - 2, 
                          TRUE ~ Date)) %>%
   select(-Day)

})
# user  system elapsed 
# 41.468   6.881  49.588 
system.time({

with(df1,  Date - setNames(rep(0:2, c(5, 1, 1)), 1:7)[format(Date, "%u")])

})
# user  system elapsed 
# 27.456   2.785  30.490
```

with `microbenchmark`,

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
   rs = df1 %>%
         mutate(Day = weekdays(Date), 
         Date = case_when(Day == "Saturday" ~ Date - 1, 
                          Day == "Sunday" ~ Date - 2, 
                          TRUE ~ Date)) %>%
   select(-Day),
ak = with(df1,  Date - setNames(rep(0:2, c(5, 1, 1)), 1:7)[format(Date, "%u")]), 
          times = 10L, unit = "relative")
#Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   rs 1.401658 1.437164 1.446403 1.421731 1.512451 1.467511    10   b
#   ak 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10  a
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Ticker = c("ABNANV", "ABNANV", "ABNANV", "ABNANV", 
"ABNANV", "ABNANV"), Date = structure(c(13575, 13576, 13584, 
13584, 14139, 14139), class = "Date"), mean_PX_ASK = c(102, 102, 
102, 102, 88.9, 88.9), mean_PX_BID = c(102, 102, 102, 102, 88.4, 
88.4), Agency = c("Moody's", "Moody's", "Moody's", "Moody's", 
"Fitch", "Fitch")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can use `format.Date` with format string `%u`.

```
dates <- as.Date(c('2007-03-02', '2007-03-03', '2007-03-04'))
wd <- as.integer(format(dates, '%u'))
as.Date(ifelse(wd >= 6, dates + 5 - wd, dates), origin = '1970-01-01')
#[1] "2007-03-02" "2007-03-02" "2007-03-02"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `wday` from lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
# Generate some data
dfdate <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-04-26"), to = as.Date("2019-04-28"), by = "day")

dfdate
[1] "2019-04-26" "2019-04-27" "2019-04-28"
```

`wday` starts on a Sunday where wday = 1

```
# Change all values to a Friday
dfdate[wday(dfdate) == 7] <-  dfdate[wday(dfdate) == 7] - 1 # Saturdays to Fri
dfdate[wday(dfdate) == 1] <-  dfdate[wday(dfdate) == 1] - 2 # Sundays to Fri

dfdate
[1] "2019-04-26" "2019-04-26" "2019-04-26"
```